# Create public or private nodes in groups

Tags: 8, flags, group

1) On my drupal 8 site, I use the "Group" and "Flags" modules.

How do I create public or private nodes in groups?

- if the node is private, it is displayed only to the member of the group.
- if a node is published, it is displayed to all users of the site.

Maybe with the module "Flags" it would be possible.

An idea ?

Comment: why did you use the "7" tag in this question? Also, what do you have available to indicate "private" (how did you implement that)?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens It's a mistake, I updated the tags. My question is how to make a private node to members of a group?

Comment: merci for fixing the tags. You did not address my last question in my comment though. PS: I don't think a "flag**S**" module exists ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I do not know. Maybe a flag could limit the node to the group. In fact I do not know how to do it at all. It's a shame that the group does not include this functionality. Group only restricts access to a content type.